# minimum value in a two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [9,2,6,5,8]
```

I am trying to find the values that match in the two arrays and the minimum of the matching values.

```
for x in list1:
    for i in list2:
        if (x == i):
            z=x
            print min(z)
```

I get an error

Comment: What do you mean by "minimum of the minimum value"?

Comment: You are setting `z` to one value in your `if`-loop. Calling `min(z)` will always return this one value.

Comment: uh at the run-time of that loop

Comment: read up on `set` in python

Comment: unclear description + presumably non-working code = how are we supposed to help?

Comment: additionally, the minimum of a single value will, tautologically, be the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [9,2,6,5,8]
list3 = set(list1).intersection(list2)
print(list3)      # {2, 5}
print(min(list3)) # 2
```

Comment: What are b1 and b2 for?

Comment: Sorry guys, I accidently posted some other code earlier. Realized it immediately. Thank you for pointing. That was a total blunder. I appolgize.

Comment: Fine solution, but calling the resulting `set` "list3" seems strange.

Answer (score 3):

```
min(set(list1) & set(list2), default=None)
```